# get aspxcombobox css class name

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

Im adding dynamically some aspxcombobox controls to my page. Each time I add one I add specified cssclass to it. Is it then possible to get that controls cssclass from javascript ?

Thanks for any hints

Answer (score 1):

the CssClass is the class field on an html element. So to get it from javascript easily

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the editor is inside a NamingContainer, for example, WebUserControl, or TabControl or any template, I would suggest that you set the editor's [ClientInstanceName](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxEditBase_ClientInstanceNametopic) property.  This property was specially designed to allow our users access the corresponding client side java script objects.  For example, if the ClientInstanceName is set to the combo value, the code would be:

```
var class = combo.GetMainElement().className;
```